# Visual Basic Excel - Apagar nome de um array

Tags: array, microsoft-excel, vba, basic

Estou aqui com uns problemas, nunca mexi em Visual Basic e estava a ver se me ajudava a fazer uma listagem que tenho em Excel mais rápido (Através do Visual Basic do Excel).

É muito simples, apenas quero procurar no array se tem alguma palavra que tenha menos de 3 letras e se tiver, apagar a palavra ou fazer `replace` por "" (que julgo ser para não ter nada também)

Eu tinha algo assim, mas não está funcionando, retorna:

> Object required

Meu código:

```
  nome = Target(1, 1)
  nomesArray = Split(nome)
  Dim i As Integer
  i = 0
  While i < UBound(nomesArray, 1)
      If Len(nomesArray(i)) < 3 Then
          nomesArray.Value = Replace(nomesArray.Value, nomesArray(i), "")
      End If
      i = i + 1
  Wend
```

Alguém consegue ajudar por favor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays em VBA (*Visual Basic For Application*) não são objetos, assim eles não possuem métodos ou atributos.

Portanto, **nomesArray.value** não pode ser utilizado, já que o array não possui atribuitos. Arrays em VBA são como Arrays em C e C++.

Baseado no que você precisa fazer, modifiquei o seu código, veja abaixo:

```
nome = Target(1, 1)
nomesArray = Split(nome)
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
While i < UBound(nomesArray, 1)
  If Len(nomesArray(i)) < 3 Then
      nomesArray(i) = ""
  End If
  i = i + 1
Wend
```

Note que a única modificação foi trocar a maneira como você atribui o valor vazio para a posição do vetor que tem menos de 3 posições.

Enfim, o array continuará do mesmo tamanho, porém com posições que tem valor = "".

Comment: Obrigado! Ajudou :)